# Force to download file(sound,video) and and file from url use php

Tags: php, download

Hello i need help to Force Download File 
i have download link for file like this

`https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/WSIkwY864LX0.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vV1NJa3dZODY0TFgwLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE1MTg4Njc5MjF9fX1dfQ__&Signature=D8mLMEF87phwsYauLxjeHVuPhYYyC~rVu901PnMNJzRX1WoYEQz3-t05OVfDJD5KQPN-mt2IXIW9SEjSy8ASWkD3esS4MQ9DoRRzLmlp84Irsj65LeyonJAj-3gvi~XVEoGkcwNQgWKNDlHpT8gJmjGwgiMsRwEfH5uBfLcKd2Vw9l9DlaFEk332reKvoI3lZuNpiNktGfNsxZWDYNzI-aqg4HvB1NHomnNl4XhnoZkXCMXVhT7p4IUM6Lxi8wFjKbrhoNupVqO-BEJfv4Gc7G4VDS5Jzmhzj6o~GZn~HYpa10RB208CCwpcg8gtaouhNhkwArozMWq74PDfz4447w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ`

this link for mp3 file when i click on it i can't download it just play it in browser 
if i set like in IDM (internet download manager )
it will download

[Click here to show image from idm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4yv6.png)

i try pass url in post or get but doesn`t work

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['comment']) && !empty($_POST['comment'])){

    $file = $_POST['comment'];
    header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
    header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with php rather you need to edit the `.htaccess` file. and this will force the mp3 files to download rather than playing

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

One more idea, Add it in the `.htaccess` I got it from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/)

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && !empty($_POST['comment'])){
    $fileName = 'test.mp3';
    $file = $_POST['comment'];
    ob_start();
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"');
    file_put_contents($fileName, $file);
    readfile($fileName);
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: yes it`s force download file but not correct file 
because file link too long

Comment: no error just download mp3 file in server and not the correct file